# cURL a website with variable GET parameters from a file

Tags: bash, variables, curl, wget

I need to cURL a website "https://example.com/api/v1/users?param0=200&param1=1", param1's value needs to change from 1 to a list of values that change with every request, separated by newlines.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm not sure where to start, I haven't found the answer by searching myself but perhaps I didn't search well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Read loop?

```
while read p1; do curl "https://example.com/api/v1/users?param0=200&param1=$p1"; done < listfile
```